# Scanner and String Comparison

Tags: java, string

I have the following text in a file :

```
3
apple   4 1.00 
chicken 1 3.25 
cookie 38 0.25
avocado 1 4.00 
blueberries 1 5.00 
chicken 2 3.25 
milk    9 4.50 
tomato 27 0.50 
chicken 2 3.25
```

I want to list each item and its number and its price but I want that if I encounter the same item again to add its number to the existing number I have

I figured out the first part but I can't get the second any one has any ideas ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner  sc = new Scanner(new File("Groceries.txt"));
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String line=sc.nextLine();
            Scanner ss = new Scanner(line);
            if(ss.hasNextInt()) {
                ss.next();
            }
            while(ss.hasNext()) {
                String name=ss.next();
                int number = readInt(ss);
                double price = ss.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf("The item is %s its number is %d and its price is %.1f\n",name,number,price);
            }
        }
    }
    public static int readInt(Scanner sc) {
        while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            sc.hasNext();
        }
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: so you will have chicken 4 3.25 in screen ? any chance we could have two different prices for an item ?

Comment: Are we supposed to average the price of duplicates?

Comment: Yes exactly chicken 4 3.25 !!

Answer (score 1):

Create a container object like so:

```
public class Container
{
     private String item;
     private double cost;
     ...
}
```

Use a `HashMap<Container, Double>` as your data structure.  Every time you come across a duplicate, update its value.

If there is a possibility for an arbitrary amount of repeats, you can use do the following:

```
public class ValueContainer
{
    private int count;
    private double value;
}
```

and have a `HashMap<Container, ValueContainer>`, and update accordingly.  There seems to be some confusion between what you say in the question and in a comment.  Regardless, with simple substitutions, this construct will get you to where you want to go.

Comment: I'm curious, why use double instead of Integer, if we assume that an item cannot be split into halves or decimals? Use of Double for the cost I understand, though not the HashMap.

Comment: @DanielB OP said something about averaging.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class describing the attributes of your item (name, price, quantity , count etc).
2. Create a list of items (Yes, use generics..) // u can also use a map instead of a list..
3. Now, with each line you read from the text file, first get the item name using split().
4. Check if the item is already present. If yes, take it out, increment its count and put it back. if No, then add a new item to the list.
5. Happy Coding...